# Using more than the last 3 scores to analyse data; also repeating analysis?

Tags: python, average

I've calculated the average and the highest score per name. However. If I have the following values saved in a text file, this is what the results show:

```
matt 5
matt 2
matt 3
andy 1
andy 2
andy 3
andy 4
matt 4
matt 's average from the last 3 scores is 4.0
andy 's average from the last 3 scores is 4.0
matt 's average from the last 3 scores is 4.0
andy -'s best score is 4
matt -'s best score is 5
```

It seems to be repeating the first name (i.e. matt's average twice and looping over it?)
Also it is producing the data based on each of the scores, not just the last 3?

```
user_scores = {}
for line in reversed(open("Class1.txt").readlines()):
    name, score = line.split()
    score = int(score)
```

Comment: Use Tree method for creating data. Can use with `ast.literal_eval(line.strip())`

Comment: Thanks is there an easier way?

Comment: Do you want the output sorted alphabetically by name, or by the numeric value (top score/average)?

Comment: Both. Each persons best score Alphabetically and also their average but also all scores high to low!

Comment: That is not possible. You can either sort the average scores alphabetically (Alice: 4, Bob: 2, Charlie: 5) or by value (Charlie: 5, Alice: 4, Bob: 2). Same for the best scores.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's an indentation error. You want this block below to be on the first indentation level:

```
for name in sorted(user_scores):
    # get the highest score in the list
    average = sum(user_scores[name]) /float(len(user_scores[name]))   
    print(name, "'s average from the last 3 scores is", average)
```

Also, there are many places where your code is written in a bad way. Here's an optimization:

```
user_scores = {}

# 'with' will automatically closes the file after leaving its code block:
with open("Class1.txt") as scorefile:  

    for line in reversed(scorefile.readlines()):  
        name, score = line.split()

        # nested if inside if/else is better than if-and plus if not:
        if name in user_scores:
            if len(user_scores[name]) < 3:
                user_scores[name].append(int(score))
        else:
            user_scores[name] = [int(score)]

# If you want to sort by the numeric value, replace 'sorted(user_scores)' with 
# 'sorted(user_scores, key=lambda k: user_scores[k])':
for name in sorted(user_scores):
    # in Python 3 the '/' operator always returns the appropriate format.
    # to get a pure integer division without decimal places, you would use '//'.
    # Therefore no need for the float(...) conversion.
    average = sum(user_scores[name]) / len(user_scores[name])
    # str.format(...) is more flexible than just printing multiple items:
    print("{}'s average from the last 3 scores is {}".format(name, average))

# No need to store another dictionary with best scores.
# If you want to sort by the numeric value, replace 'sorted(user_scores)' with 
# 'sorted(user_scores, key=lambda k: user_scores[k])':
for name in sorted(user_scores):
    print("{}'s best score is {}".format(name, max(user_scores[name])))
```

Comment: I'm getting an error message on line 33:    for line in reversed(scorefile):
TypeError: argument to reversed() must be a sequence

Comment: @Canadian1010101 Sorry, my mistake. You need the readlines() there. Corrected that in my answer.

Comment: Ive tested it and it covers all of the scores rather then just the last three scores so the average and highest score ends up being for all of them?

Comment: @Canadian1010101 You're right, I copied that mistake from your original code without testing it. It has to be `if len(user_scores[name]) < 3:` (not `<= 3`. Otherwise it takes the last 4 scores.

Comment: Also please don't forget to accept this answer by clicking the grey tick symbol on the left of it once it solves your problem.